# Do the octonions form a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-algebras, octonions

The [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) are a noncommutative nonassociative normed division algebra over $\mathbb{R}$. Multiplication distributes over addition. Somehow, the existence of a norm implies the existence of multiplicative inverses.

Since multiplication is not associative, the nonzero octonions are not a group, but a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup). I wonder if the octonions can still be regarded as a "field", though, or if there's a more proper name for them.

Comment: A "non-associative division algebra" maybe?

Comment: Fields are basically *always* defined to be associative and almost always defined to be commutative. But, paradoxically,  Lord Shark the Unknown's comment is true that it is less rare for "division algebras" to omit associativity from the list of axioms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have answered your own question since a field must have an associative product, yet the octonions are not associative.

Although multiplication is not associative, it is *alternative* and *flexible*.

Suppose $x$ and $y$ are elements of the octionions $\mathbb{O}$.

Then

1. $(xx)y=x(xy)$
2. $x(yy)=(xy)y$
3. $(xy)x=x(yx)$

The first two properties make $\mathbb{O}$ *alternative* the third makes it *flexible*.

Comment: The usual definition of division ring also requires associativity. It's the Quaternions that are notable for being a division ring.

Comment: @Hurkyl, You are correct, I will amend my answer.